# Java Neo4j reduce the number of transactions to improve the performance

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to generate a Neo4j database using Java based on the computation of Kleene matrix. To simplify, each node has an id with the form `m&n` where m and n are integers, and for each level `i` in this graph, I want to find all nodes with id's as `*&i` and `i&*` so I can combine them to get new nodes with `i` as an intermediate node. For example, the current level is 2, then from nodes whose id's are `1&2` and `2&3`, it can create a new node with id `1&3`. And it also connects the new nodes to its parent nodes.
And my codes look like this:

```
foreach(level i){
   foreach(nodeid id_m ends with i){//
      foreach(nodeid id_n starts with i){
          try(Transaction tx = graph.beginTx()){
            Node m = tx.findNode(id_m);
            Node n = tx.findNode(id_n);
            Node newNode = tx.createNode();
            newNode.setProperties(...);
            newNode.createRelationshipTo(m);
            newNode.createRelationshipTo(n);
            tx.commit();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Both `id_m` and `id_n` are searched and put in lists by Java function in the outer loop. Each time when the code creates a new node, it commits the transaction once. However when there are a huge number of new nodes created(approximately millions of new nodes), it gets incredibly slow(more than 4 hours, which is not acceptable).
I was thinking about the following solutions:

1. using multithreads to create these nodes, but it might not suit my case since each time creating a relationship between two nodes, both nodes will be locked until it's committed, and the same nodes might appear in different threads.
2. saving the new node information to a queue and commit it to Neo4j database when its size is too large. However without new nodes created to the database, it's not able to connect them with their parents. So it seems like impossible to reduce the number of transactions.

So is there any other possible ways to improve the performance of this code? Or is it possible to implement this by Neo4j clauses? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you making DB queries to implement the `ends with i` and `starts with i` tests?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, this part is checked in Java method in the outer loop.